# 2022 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #2](https://latin.stackexchange.com/election/2) on Latin Language — your "graduation" election! — has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators are... the folks who were previously your pro-tem moderators!

[image: Draconis]

[image: Joonas Ilmavirta]

[image: cmw]

[image: Cerberus]

Please thank them for volunteering and standing for re-election!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://latin.stackexchange.com/election/2) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5363518730665984).

Comment: Many thanks for your support, everyone!

Comment: Congrats! Very well deserved for all four.

Comment: @Adam: I do think you'd be good at moderating.

Comment: Congratulations to all the moderators and volunteers who stood, your time and efforts are greatly appreciated.